# Get information from javascript on HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to access information from my JavaScript code on my HTML. I know HTML is not a programming code, but I just wanted to know if this is possible. Currently working with WebGL with a 3D image.

Here is some part of my code:

**HTML**:

```
void main()
{

    fColor = vColor;
    gl_Position = rotateZ(theta.z) * rotateY(theta.y) * rotateX(theta.x) * vPosition;
    gl_Position.z = -gl_Position.z;
    gl_Position.x=gl_Position.x+transX;
    gl_Position.y=gl_Position.y+transY;
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
document.getElementById("translateX").onchange = function(event){
  transX = parseFloat(event.target.value);
  init();
  };
document.getElementById("translateY").onchange = function(event){
  transY = parseFloat(event.target.value);
  init();
  };
```

"TranslateX" and "TranslateY" are sliders, where if I change them I want it to modify the variable on the HTML so the image is translated.

Comment: The code you've labeled HTML looks more like C. Where is your HTML?

Comment: is someone forcing you to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about CSS variables?

Comment: Here is my whole code, you won't be able to see the actual image because I'm using libraries from a protected source, so...
https://codepen.io/DanielCS31044/pen/QWbgGmP?editors=1010

Comment: @Lakakid html  code that you have mentioned is js code in your html file please mention it accordingly in the question,

Answer (score 0):

make a function and call this in html code using `onclick="yourfunctionname()"`

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about clicking on things?